# Problems displaying lists - styling

Tags: html, css, list

My issue is with lists on a menu I've created.

I want it set so that when I hover over a menu item the list displays below! I also have one other section within a list, that has a sub-list that I want to show up when hovering over it as well.

My issue is when I hover over the menu button, both lists show up. Could anyone help me out with this?  Thanks guys.

```
    <li><a href="/specialityservices/criticalcare.php" accesskey="4" title="">SPECIALTY SERVICE &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="/specialityservices/criticalcare.php">Critical Care</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/specialityservices/internalmedicine.php">Internal Medicine</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/specialityservices/surgery.php">Surgery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/specialityservices/rehab.php">;Rehab</a>
                          <ul>
                          <li><a href="/specialityservices/rehab.php">Rehab 101</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/specialityservices/whattoexpect.php">What To Expect</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/specialityservices/services.php">&nbsp;Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/specialityservices/conditionstreated.php">Conditions Treated</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/specialityservices/catscorner.php">Cat's Corner</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                   </ul>
            </li>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
height: 60px;
background: url(images/subpage1_02.gif) no-repeat left top;
font-family: 'Kameron', serif; 
}

ul {
z-index: 4;
font-family: 'Kameron', serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 18px;
list-style: none;
}

ul li {
z-index: 5;
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
li ul {
display: none;
}
ul li a {
z-index: 6;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 18px 0px 0px 0px;
background: none;
margin-left: 6px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
z-index: 7;
color: #732B36;
background: none;
}
li:hover ul {
z-index: 8;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
z-index: 9;
float: none;
font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a {
z-index: 10;
background: #3d3d3d;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
z-index: 11;
background: white;
}
```

Comment: Wow, your code is convoluted. Try to use semantics to format it in a readable and easily to follow form, it will help you solve your own problems and let us find the problem easier

Comment: [**Use this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/A3Xgg/). Essentially you need to use the "direct child selector", `>`

Comment: How is it convoluted? I get that it isn't perfect and I have to work on finesse, but it seems easy enough to understand doesn't it?

Comment: It's convoluted in its lack of white space and you also have many unnecessary properties that make it more convoluted

Comment: Ahh gotcha.  Not going to lie, I self taught myself this over the last year and got into a flow where I can work with it, although I know I don't follow things to a "T"...sorry about that

Comment: As well...your tip worked. Thanks Zach

Comment: [An example of a cleaned up version](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/A3Xgg/1/). And I taught myself within the last year too (: Just because you didn't learn from someone doesn't mean you can't still be efficient

Comment: I see what you mean. A little space can go along way.  Much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that you need to use the direct child selector, `>`, for the drop down displays (the part that changes it from `display:none` to `display:block`)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/A3Xgg/1/)

I also removed unnecessary properties, added white space, and formatted the HTML more properly

Answer (score 0):

You can also put sub-level navigation in a `div` and transition `max-height` on hover. I've found this solution to be pretty effective.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8NW4v/